# ASP.NET TextBox and Button in the same control

Tags: asp.net, controls

I would like to create a single control containing a TextBox and a Button but I have never created a custom control before and I am not sure how to do it, this is what I have done :

```
namespace CustomControls
{
    public partial class TBP : TextBox
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public TBP()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(_Button);
        }

        private Button _Button = new Button();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you need _UserControl_ instead of _Custom Control_ here, but of course it depends on your requirement. Do you want to reuse it multiple projects? Check [Recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710(v=vs.71).aspx) by Microsoft first.

Comment: Will I have to redefine all the methods and properties of a textbox/button for my custom control ?

Comment: You are creating the textbox & checkbox dynamically so I would not say `redefine` rather you will have to define them all. Check for basic tutorials for both and please keep in mind Custom control is difficult as compared to User Control.

Answer (score 1):

[Creating User Control](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/creating/)

[Using a User Control](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/)

[Events in User Control](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/events/)

Take a look on this 3 articles and you will be able to work with Controls due to your request.

Comment: Thanks for the links.

Comment: @Stan you will spend maximum 15 minutes to learn, how to use that.